# Druid with queries for caculating the distence for each adjancent rows

Tags: distance, window-functions, druid

Hi I would like to calculate the distance for each two adjacent rows, for example:
row1 value: x1 , y1 , z1 and row2 value: x2, y2, z2 and the results I want is the 3D distance sqrt((x1-x2)*2 + (y1-y2)*2+ (z1-z2)*2)

Or does any one knows that there will is any function like window function LEAD so that on each row, I can get the value of the next row and then to calculate the distance?